# How to play video files (mov, mp4, ts etc etc) in a web page

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a question about playing several video files in an intranet page.

The page is really simple, there is a list with videos ordered by name and clicking one of them, it starts in the page inside video tag using JS to replace the source.

It works with MP4 files but for example mov and other files do not work or play only audio.
I understood this is a normal problem of browsers that does not support all video types, so the question is:
Is there a way to play them without convert all files to mp4?

I have access to the linux server with apache web server, ffmpeg is installed I can install other software if necessary (streaming server? file streaming? I'm not an expert) I am not interested to live events.

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Roy

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked about this question on a internal website. If I have understood, forr reading a movie ine a browser, tous client must have the codec on the client computer. (that's why, with the old flash plugin, often installed by default, the wovies was played i,n native mode)
Have you tested to download the movie that it is not playin, on your computer et launch it in the web browser, to be sure all codec are well installed?

I think it is juste a codec problem.

Comment: This is a good information but cannot help me to solve the question because if the videos use different codecs we have to download all codecs on all PCs and this could be a security issue

Comment: Yes of course. I don't know a movie format that has no codec :)
I therefore advise you to use a frequently used or often used codec